# Calls to `Workspace.PendAdd` not adding items

Tags: c#, tfs-sdk

I have the following function that is being called in a loop on two new projects to add to source control. Each iteration of the loop gets the source code, copies it to the folder, creates a tfs team project, creates a workspace for that project, and then tries to add the code to source control.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var tfsWorkItems = _<IWorkItems>();
    var workItems = tfsWorkItems.GetProjectsToMigrate();
    var tfs = _<ITfs>();
    var logFilePath = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\log");
    var workingDirectory = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\m");
    Cleanup(workItems, tfs, logFilePath, workingDirectory);
    var svn = _<ISvn>();
    var app = _<IApplication>();
    foreach (var workItem in workItems)
    {
        var root = Path.Combine(workingDirectory.FullName, workItem.Id.ToString());
        var svnBase = Path.Combine(root, "s");
        var localWorkspacePath = Path.Combine(root, "t");
        var tfsBase = Path.Combine(localWorkspacePath, workItem.TfsProjectName, "Main");
        var tfsProject = workItem.ProjectType.ToLower() == "php" ? Path.Combine(tfsBase, "src")
                                                                    : tfsBase;
        svn.CheckoutFromSvn(workItem.SvnLocation, svnBase);
        app.CopyToTfsFolderStructure(svnBase, tfsProject);
        tfs.CreateTeamProject(workItem.TfsProjectName, logFilePath);
        tfs.CreateWorkspace(workItem.WorkspaceName, localWorkspacePath);
        tfs.AddToSourceControl(workItem.WorkspaceName, localWorkspacePath, workItem.TfsProjectName);
    }
}
```

There are two projects. The first project works correctly, but the second does not. The second project creates the project and workspace, but in AddToSourceControl

```
public void AddToSourceControl(string workspaceName, string localPath, string projectName) {
    var tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(_collection);
    var vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
    var user = vcs.AuthorizedUser;
    var workspace = vcs.GetWorkspace(workspaceName, user);
    var serverPath = workspace.GetServerItemForLocalItem(Path.Combine(localPath, projectName, "Main"));
    var itemSpec = new ItemSpec[] {
        new ItemSpec(serverPath, RecursionType.Full)
    };
    workspace.PendAdd(serverPath, true);

    // doesn't return anything
    var pendingSets = vcs.QueryPendingSets(
        itemSpec, workspace.Name, user, true);
    var pendingChanges = pendingSets.Aggregate(new List<PendingChange>(), (acc, item) => {
        acc.AddRange(item.PendingChanges);
        return acc;
    });
    var parameters = new WorkspaceCheckInParameters(pendingChanges, "svn to tfs migration") {
        OverrideGatedCheckIn = ((CheckInOptions2)vcs.SupportedFeatures & CheckInOptions2.OverrideGatedCheckIn) == CheckInOptions2.OverrideGatedCheckIn,
        PolicyOverride = new PolicyOverrideInfo("migration triggered check-in", null),
        SuppressEvent = true,
    };
    workspace.CheckIn(parameters);
}
```

`workspace.PendAdd(serverPath, true)` always returns zero for the second project, regardless of which project is second. The first project always completes properly. It doesn't matter which project is second. The second project always returns zero items. I obviously want all projects to be added to source control correctly. What is going on here?

Comment: It looks like you're reusing the workspace name when you call `CreateWorkspace`...?  Is it possible then that you don't end up with appropriate working folder mappings for the second call?

Comment: @EdwardThomson - no the two workspace names are svn2tfs_1 and svn2tfs_2. I have verified this by stepping through the debugger

Comment: Are you getting any non-fatal errors back from the pend add?  (This might be easier to see with Fiddler instead of a debugger, unless you've hooked up event listeners on the VersionControlServer object.)

Comment: I'm getting no exceptions from the call to PendAdd, I get an exception when trying to call CheckIn because the call to QueryPendingSets returns zero items. I verified that PendAdd is returning zero as well. I have not tried using fiddler. I would not know what to look for if I tried.

Comment: So the TFS API will not always through an exception, it also has the concept of "non-fatal errors".  For example, if you call `PendAdd` on a bunch of paths, and one of them fails, this will raise a non-fatal error for the failed path and continue.  (This could be because the path is locked on the server, for example.)  I'm a lot more familiar with the Java TFS API, so I'm not certain how to do this in the .NET one.  I'll try to find a code sample and follow-up.

Comment: Make sure to get the items from workspace first and then try giving the Folder path instead of file. somethings like  workspace.PendEdit(localDir,RecursionType.Full);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have figured out a way around this problem. I have to create a separate console application that contained the code in the `AddToSourceControl` method and call the console application via the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class. Something internally in the TFS API must not be getting released properly until the whole entire program exits.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case...  this is certainly something we do with great frequency...

Comment: I have reported a bug to microsoft here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/762074/workspace-pendadd-returns-zero-and-no-items-are-added-when-creating-projects-in-a-loop#details . It contains a fully working c# solution that shows the problem in action.

Comment: There's a lot of code in there.  But I modified your `AddToSourceControl\Program.cs` to run in a loop and it works fine.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know why your application is not working, but the TFS API is capable of creating multiple workspaces and checking in from them without any need to dispose anything or call the GC or anything strange like that.

Here's an example program, modified from the one you posted to the connect site, that exhibits correct behavior:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common;

namespace AddToSourceControl
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Uri serverUri = new Uri(args[0]);
                string serverPath = args[1];
                string localPath = args[2];

                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    string uniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                    if (i > 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Creating a workspace and checking in with id " + uniqueId);

                    TfsTeamProjectCollection connection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(serverUri);
                    VersionControlServer vcs = connection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

                    string uniqueServerPath = VersionControlPath.Combine(serverPath, uniqueId);
                    string uniqueFolder = Path.Combine(localPath, uniqueId);

                    Workspace workspace = vcs.CreateWorkspace(uniqueId, vcs.AuthorizedUser, "", new WorkingFolder[] {
                        new WorkingFolder(uniqueServerPath, uniqueFolder)
                    });

                    Console.WriteLine("Created TFS workspace " + uniqueId);

                    CheckinLocalFolder(serverUri, localPath, uniqueId);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed: " + e);
            }
        }

        private static void CheckinLocalFolder(Uri serverUri, string localPath, string uniqueId)
        {
            TfsTeamProjectCollection connection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(serverUri);
            VersionControlServer vcs = connection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

            string uniqueFolder = Path.Combine(localPath, uniqueId);
            string uniqueFile = Path.Combine(uniqueFolder, uniqueId + ".txt");

            Workspace workspace = vcs.GetWorkspace(uniqueFolder);

            Console.Out.WriteLine("Found workspace " + workspace.Name);

            // Create a local folder with a file in it
            Directory.CreateDirectory(uniqueFolder);
            using (TextWriter output = new StreamWriter(uniqueFile))
            {
                output.WriteLine("This is " + uniqueId);
                output.Close();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Created file " + uniqueFile);

            workspace.PendAdd(uniqueFolder, true);

            PendingChange[] pendingChanges = workspace.GetPendingChanges();

            Console.WriteLine("Pended changes:");
            foreach (PendingChange pendingChange in pendingChanges)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" " + pendingChange.LocalItem + " (" + pendingChange.ChangeType + ")");
            }

            int changeset = workspace.CheckIn(pendingChanges, "Test from id " + uniqueId);

            Console.WriteLine("Checked in " + pendingChanges.Length + " as changeset " + changeset);
        }
    }
}
```

So I would suggest that the problem lies elsewhere in your code.  However, if you can produce a [short, self-contained example](http://sscce.org) that exhibits the problem without many layers of abstraction, that would be helpful.

Some helpful tips:

**Make sure your workspace mappings are setup correctly**: otherwise, calling `PendAdd` recursively will not, in fact, add anything.

**Make sure the files exist locally**: for the same reason.

**Listen for errors:**
The TFS API has several events that it can notify consumers of - one that is particularly useful is the "non fatal" error notifications.  In many operations, one part of an operation can fail, and instead of exiting or throwing an exception, a "non fatal" will be raised and the operation will continue.

An example of this is when you're adding multiple paths to `PendAdd` and one of them fails (for example, because a path is locked.)  Without listening to non fatal errors, you will not know that this path is excluded from the pending changes.  (Though you will know that *a* path is excluded, due to looking at the return code.)

If you have a `VersionControlServer vcs`:

```
public class Example
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        VersionControlServer vcs = ConnectToServer(); // ... etc ...
        vcs.NonFatalError += Example.OnNonFatalError;
    }

    internal static void OnNonFatalError(Object sender, ExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Exception != null)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("  Non-fatal exception: " + e.Exception.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("  Non-fatal failure: " + e.Failure.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

*(Note that this example was taken from Buck Hodges' helpful [client API example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2012/03/10/team-foundation-version-control-client-api-example-for-tfs-2010-and-newer.aspx) blog post.)*

Comment: I added a handler for the `NonFatalError` event, it never fired.

Comment: How interesting, the only thing that is different is you are holding onto the instances of the `TfsTeamProjectCollection` and `VersionControlServer`, reusing those instances. My loop creates new instances of these in each iteration twice, once to create the workspace, and then again to add them to source control. Once again reaffirming my conclusion that something is not being released properly, and narrowing it down to something inside one of the afore mentioned classes. I would use your code, but I would have to rewrite the whole program. I don't have time to do that, and my solution works.

Comment: I added your sample loop to the bug I posted. The information is very helpful.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but I think that your assumption that the API isn't releasing something properly is flawed.  I changed the program above to create a new `TfsTeamProjectCollection` and `VersionControlServer` each time and - as expected - it works fine.  Can you repro this behavior in a simpler manner or, more to the point, can you show that this is a bug in the TFS API and not in your code?

Comment: Moving code unchanged from inside of a method in my application into a separate console application and calling that code, unchanged would indicate resource management issues. Code does not magically change how it executes by simply moving it from one place to the other. In certain cases managed resources are cleaned up at program completion time (e.g. static members exist until the AppDomain is unloaded). Also, not every call into .NET methods are managed code. Memory leaks from unmanaged code items allocated on the heap do not get unloaded until the application exits.

Comment: Yes, I understand your opinIon here.  I didn't make a console app "unchanged" from yours, I posted sample code derived from the console app you posted to the connect site.  The rest of the code on the connect site contains abstractions that are unhelpful for illustrating a supposed bug in TFS, since there could be a bug in the abstraction layer.   Also, there's no unmanaged code in the version control object model.  Are you suggesting that with the literal above code, sans abstractions, you can illustrate this problem while running as a web app?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem (even the MSDN sample did not work on my machine), but listening to [non fatal errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.nonfatalerror(v=vs.120).aspx) gave me the hint to invoke [Workstation.EnsureUpdateWorkspaceInfoCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb139687(v=vs.120).aspx) **before** calling PendAdd.
This solved it for me.

Comment: +1 for non-fatal events.  I had an issue where a TFS dll was failing to load which resulted in added files just not being added.  Non-fatal events helped me understand the actual issue was failure to resolve an assembly

Answer (score 1):

I was stucked with the command PenAdd and, like Wobuntu, the command :

```
Workstation.Current.EnsureUpdateWorkspaceInfoCache( _versionControl, _versionControl.AuthenticatedUser);
```

solved the problem for me.

You need to call this method before the command PenAdd.

Answer (score 1):

```
Workstation.Current.EnsureUpdateWorkspaceInfoCache(
                                                _versionControl, 
                                                _versionControl.AuthenticatedUser
                                               );
```

This is the correct solution and it worked for me.