# C# TFS Workspace.PendADD No working mapping for the folder

Tags: c#, tfs, version-control

I am trying to add a file to TFS through C# . Here is my code.

```
 Workspace workspace = versionControl.QueryWorkspaces(Environment.MachineName, versionControl.AuthorizedUser, Environment.MachineName).SingleOrDefault();
        if (workspace == null)
        {
            w("No workspace configured");
            return;
        }

        //String topDir = null;

       var troubleshooter = workspace.GetWorkingFolderForLocalItem("LocalPath");  

workspace.PendAdd("Filepath", true);
```

Its weird that when I call workspace.GeWorkingFolderForLocalItem it works fine and gets the folder mapping. Issue arises when I try to PendADD a file in TFS from the same path then Fatal Error occures stating that no Working mapping found for the "LocalPath".

Any Guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the problem was in the cache for VersionControlServer. Cache was not fully updated that is why "GetWorkingFolderforServerItem" was working well and PendAdd was not. PendAdd Use cache. Following command did the trick.

```
            Workstation.Current.EnsureUpdateWorkspaceInfoCache(versionControl, versionControl.AuthorizedUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your error info, make sure **your workspace mappings are setup** correctly: otherwise, calling `workspace.PendAdd` recursively will not, in fact, add anything. Please see the detail explanation in the *Edward Thomson*'s answer of this question: [Calls to `Workspace.PendAdd` not adding items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355585/calls-to-workspace-pendadd-not-adding-items)

And here is another [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2012/03/10/team-foundation-version-control-client-api-example-for-tfs-2010-and-newer/) from MSDN show how to create a workspace, pending changes, check in those changes for your reference.

Comment: Thanks mate but mappings are there and working well. As explained in question when I try to "GetWorkingFolderForServerItem" it returns the expected value