# Mark project changes as pending in source control

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I have a small C# console program which uses the AddItem() method of Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project to add several language .resx files to all the Projects in several Solutions.  This is working fine.

The issue is, those changes do not appear as pending changes in source control.  I would like to see the .csproj files marked as pending change and the new .resx as pending adds.  What APIs should be used to do this?  I found the SccAdd() native API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/sccadd-function) but it looks like something that would need to be called by the IDE, not from my command line utility.

Environment:  The c# console program is VS2015.  The projects it is modifying are VS2008 Compact Framework 3.5.  The current Source Control system is TFS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **TFS API** to pend changes in a workspace then check in files to TFS. Use the  [Workspace.PendAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb139335(v=vs.120).aspx) method  queues files or a folder for addition to the version-control repository. Either create a temporarily workspace or use the one your project file located.

Here is a detail [example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2012/03/10/team-foundation-version-control-client-api-example-for-tfs-2010-and-newer/) of using the TFS API to add pending changes, checkin code. You could aslo  take a look at this question: [Calls to `Workspace.PendAdd` not adding items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355585/calls-to-workspace-pendadd-not-adding-items)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look into that.  I was hoping to find something that wouldn't require my utility to be aware of TFS specifics but would rather use whatever source control bindings existed for that VS Solution.